# If $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ are iid, how to show that $E(Y_1 | T = \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i) = \frac{T}{n}$?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution

Suppose I have that $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ are iid. I saw a line in a book that said that if $T = \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$, then:

$$
E(Y_1 | T) = \frac{T}{n}
$$

I am lost as to how they obtain this. One approach I did was:

$$
E(Y_1 | T) = E\left(Y_1 | \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i = t\right)  = E\left(Y_1 | Y_1 = t-\sum_{i=2}^{n}Y_i \right) = E\left(T-\sum_{i=2}^{n}Y_i\right) = T- (n-1)\lambda
$$

However, I know this is wrong but dont know why.

Comment: In Casella Berger, Statistical Inference

Comment: Could you tell me the page of the book where you found this statement?

Answer (score 3):

By linearity of expectation (since $T=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i$):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathsf E(Y_i\mid T) = \mathsf E(T\mid T)$$

Then by symmetry (since they are *identical and independent*): $$n~\mathsf E(Y_1\mid T)=T$$

That is all.

---

Where you went wrong is that the condition that $T=t$ affects all $Y_i$ and must "remain in play" when you replace $Y_1$ in step $\star$.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E\left(Y_1 ~\middle\vert~ T=t\right) = & ~ \mathsf E\left(Y_1 ~\middle\vert~ \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i = t\right) \\ = & \mathsf E\left(Y_1 ~\middle\vert~ Y_1 = t-\sum_{i=2}^{n}Y_i, \color{red}{T=t} \right) \\ = & \mathsf E\left(T-\sum_{i=2}^{n}Y_i ~\middle\vert~ \color{red}{T=t}\right) & \star
\\ = & ~ \mathsf E(T\mid T=t) - \color{red}{\sum_{i=2}^n \mathsf E\left(Y_i~\middle\vert~T=t\right)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for the post! I am just wondering, are there a set of general rules for when one can "pull" things out of the conditional part vs. leaving it there?

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are independent Poisson random variables with parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$, the distribution of $X_i$ given $T=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is the binomial distribution with parameters $T$ and $\lambda_i/\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j$, that is,
$$
X_i\sim\mathrm{Binom}\biggl(T,\frac{\lambda_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j}\biggr)
$$
(see, for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Related_distributions)). 
In our case, $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\ldots=\lambda_n=\lambda$. Hence,
$$
\operatorname E[X_1\mid T]=T\cdot\frac{\lambda_1}{\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j}=T\cdot\frac{\lambda}{n\lambda}=\frac Tn.
$$
I am not sure if there is a simpler way to evaluate $\operatorname E[X_1\mid T]$. I hope this is useful.

Comment: Can you tell me how you get $E[X_1\mid T]=T\cdot\frac{\lambda_1}{\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j}$? Is there a more formal way of doing this? For example, is there a way to view this via definition of expectation: $E(X_1 | T) =\sum x P(X_1 = x | T)$?

Comment: If $\xi\sim\mathrm{Binom}(n,p)$, then $\operatorname E\xi=np$. I am not sure if there is a simpler way to calculate $\operatorname E[X_1,\mid T]$.